# How to compare two columns and return value from a third column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

sample data

```
sample = ({'name':['Delinquency Rate','Cumulative Probability'],
           'value':['Dlnqy','Prbblty'],
           'new_name':['Dlnqncy Rt','Cmltv Prbblty']})

test = pd.DataFrame(sample)

test
```

new_name is created by removing all the vowels from 'name'. I want to compare first 3 characters of 'value' and first 3 character of 'each of the word' in 'new_name' and if they match I want to return the value from the name column. For example 'Dln' in value exists in 'Dlnqncy' of new_name, so we will return 'Delinquency' from name. The logic should work like

```
'if value[:3] in new_name[:3] then return name'
```

Following is what I have so far, which works fine if I have only two columns. But it doesn't work
if I want to compare value and new_name and retun name.

```
def get_matches(name, value, new_name, default=''):
    return next( (word for word in new_name.split() if str(value)[:3] in word[:3]),default)


test['match'] = test[['name', 'value', 'new_name']].apply(lambda row: get_matches(*row, default=' '), axis=1)
```

In the following table the column 'match' should have 'Delinquency' and 'Probability' (as it is there in the 'name' column)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
(test
 .assign(match=lambda x: np.where((x.new_name.str[:3] == x.value.str[:3]), x.name, x.value))
)
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it and spending time to solve it. This returns 'Delinquency Rate', 'Prbblty' for the 'match' column. What I need is 'Delinquency' and 'Probability' - the matching word from 'name' column not the whole string.

Comment: Ok, what will it return if it is not a match?

Comment: It will return blank or null for no match